# Odd requests in the http server access log

Tags: http

I switched to Nnginx from Apache, and took a look at the access logs. There are some requests scanning for phpMyAdmin etc, but I was surprised to find requests for weird sites. For example:

```
156.201.91.152 - - [14/Nov/2018:23:43:14 +0100] "GET http://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 234 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

I have no clue what `yastatic.net` or `bootstrap.min.css` are. I have a number of those isolated requests giving 404. I went to check the access log for my old Apache instance, and there they can be found too, but with a 302 status code.

Any clue what that is about?

A got other weird ones. Here is someone asking for `http://www.bing.com/`, apparently coming from a google search results page:

```
46.119.114.237 - - [14/Nov/2018:23:15:58 +0100] "GET http://www.bing.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5616 "http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%3Ctitle%3EBing%3C%2Ftitle%3E%20www.bing.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729) (Prevx 3.0.5)"
```

Comment: There's some information on this [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/url-from-another-domain-in-my-access-log). It looks like someone is port scanning your server for vulnerabilities.

Comment: What was your site hosting before? You mention Nginx and Apache as if that switch means something. It doesn’t. All you are noticing is Apache would redirect these requests to your root (I assume) and Nginx is simply dropping dead in it’s tracks. The reality is your site is being probed with tons of fake requests by a bot scanning you. Don’t take it personally: Every website in the modern world is being endlessly scanned. I would not lose sleep over this.

Answer (score -1):

Someone is asking your server for the page http://yastatic.net...   We can only speculate at the reasons why.

I think the most likely cause is either a bot which is incorrectly configured or something trying to fingerprint / exploit your system.   There are other possible explanations but they would seem less likely as the IP addresses requesting this change are very different over a not-that-long time period.  Similarly the browser strings are very different and appear to have been picked up from someone elses logs.

Comment: Why the downvote?